# Automatically save incoming/outgoing messages to hard drive

Tags: vba, events, outlook, event-handling

I have 2 codes that work separately (if I delete one and keep the other).

This is to save incoming messages.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String

  enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

  sName = Item.Subject
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

  dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
  sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

' use My Documents for older Windows.
    sPath = enviro & "\Documents\"
  Debug.Print sPath & sName
  Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

  End If

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

This is to save outgoing messages:

```
    Private WithEvents objSentItems As Items
    Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim objSent As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objSentItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
    Set objNS = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub objSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
      Dim sPath As String
      Dim dtDate As Date
      Dim sName As String
      Dim enviro As String

    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

      sName = Item.Subject
      ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

      dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
      sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
        vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
        vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

        sPath = enviro & "\Documents\"
      Debug.Print sPath & sName
      Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
      sChr As String _
    )
      sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
      sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
      sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
      sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
      sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
      sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
      sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
      sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
    End Sub
```

How would I combine these 2 so incoming and outgoing messages are saved? When I try running both it gives me an error that I can't have 2 "private withevents". I put this in "ThisoutlookSession".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents objSentItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace

  Dim objSent As Outlook.MAPIFolder


  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items



  Set objSentItems = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items

End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String

  enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

  sName = Item.Subject
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

  dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
  sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"


    sPath = enviro & "\Documents\"
  Debug.Print sPath & sName
  Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMsg

  End If

End Sub
Private Sub objSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
      Dim sPath As String
      Dim dtDate As Date
      Dim sName As String
      Dim enviro As String

    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

      sName = Item.Subject
      ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

      dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
      sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
        vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
        vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

        sPath = enviro & "\Documents\"
      Debug.Print sPath & sName
      Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMsg
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents objSentItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim Ns As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim objSent As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  Set objSentItems = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String

  enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

  sName = Item.Subject
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

  dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
  sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

' use My Documents for older Windows.
    sPath = enviro & "\Documents\"
  Debug.Print sPath & sName
  Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

  End If

End Sub
Private Sub objSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
      Dim sPath As String
      Dim dtDate As Date
      Dim sName As String
      Dim enviro As String

    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

      sName = Item.Subject
      ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

      dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
      sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
        vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
        vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

        sPath = enviro & "\Documents\"
      Debug.Print sPath & sName
      Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, when i tried this before what happens is that i get a compile error of Variable not defined at line: Set ObjNS = Application.,GetNamespace("Mapi") 

I'm assuming because its already sharing the 
Set Ns = Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI") right above it?  

Upvote for the help!

Comment: omg, i just commented on the solution, and its the same thing you did.  Thanks!